# GetScheduled-Job doesn't return any job

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to use PowerShell to add a trigger to an existing scheduled task.
I'm using Windows 10 & PowerShell 5

When I run:

```
Get-Scheduled-Job -Name TASK_NAME
```

I receive the error:

```
>Get-ScheduledJob : A scheduled job definition with Name sanityInstaller could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ScheduledJob sanityInstaller
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-ScheduledJob], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScheduledJobDefinitionNotFoundByName,Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.GetScheduledJobCommand
```

It seems that even when I run the same command with no parameter it's expected to return all jobs but it returns an empty result.

In the Task Scheduler there's no such folder as `/Microsoft/Windows/PowerShell/ScheduledJobs` and even after I created it and a new task inside it doesn't return it.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Get-ScheduledJob gets only scheduled jobs that are created by the
>   current user using the Register-ScheduledJob cmdlet.

[Source](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223923).

You are looking for the [Get-ScheduledTask](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=287549) cmdlet.

Comment: I have another machine running Win7 where the [Get-ScheduledTask](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=287549) cmdlet doesn't work, is there a way around this ?

Comment: Thanks for this, this really oblivious to me... I was able to hack this by first running Register-ScheduleJob and only then edit what I needed inside the job. Also, for future reference, the tasks created by Register-ScheduleJob are always executed using powershell and their xmls and results are saved @ C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs, in task scheduler you can find them under Microsoft/Windows/PowerShell/ScheduleJobs